# Hadoop distcp not working

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I am trying to copy data from one HDFS to another HDFS. Any suggestion why 1st one works but not 2nd one?

(works)

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://abc.net:8020/foo/bar webhdfs://def.net:14000/bar/foo
```

(does not work )

```
hadoop distcp webhdfs://abc.net:50070/foo/bar webhdfs://def:14000/bar/foo
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the error log

Comment: do you think both ways are correct? Source and destination are in different versions of Hadoop

Comment: if source has lower version of MR and destination has higher version of MR then, there should be issue. to overcome this you should use `webhdfs`. Your both ways seems ok, but in your second command destination namenode port should be `50070`. Can you cross check if its running on right port. You can verify it by accessing it through web browser.

Comment: WebHDFS concept is based on HTTP operations like GET, PUT, POST and DELETE. Hence NameNode HTTP port should be given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two cluster are running incompatible version of HDFS, then
you can use the `webhdfs`protocol to `distcp` between them.

```
hadoop distcp webhdfs://namenode1:50070/source/dir webhdfs://namenode2:50070/destination/dir
```

NameNode URI and NameNode `HTTP` port should be provided in the source and destination command, if you are using `webhdfs`.